why caffeine Caching just work with new initialization in my code?
I wrote a simple code to test caffeine cache in spring boot:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {

 private String id;
 private String name;
}


a class for create book data
@Component
public class DataBuilder{

    public Book getBook(String id){
        for(Book book: getBooks()){
            if(book.getId().equals(id))return book;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<Book> getBooks(){
        List<Book> books= new ArrayList<>();
        Book book1 =  new Book("1","ali1");
        Book book2 =  new Book("2","ali2");
        Book book3 =  new Book("3","ali3");
        Book book4 =  new Book("4","ali4");
        Book book5 =  new Book("5","ali5");
        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);
        books.add(book3);
        books.add(book4);
        books.add(book5);
        return books;

    }
}

a class for caching
@Service
public class BookProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private DataBuilder dataBuilder;

    @Cacheable(value = "books",key = "#id")
    public Book getBook(String id){
        return dataBuilder.getBook(id);
    }
}


and a class for call cached data:
@Service
@DependsOn("applicationContextProvider")
public class Readers {


    private BookProcessor bookProcessor = ApplicationContextProvider.getAppCtx().getBean(BookProcessor.class);


    public Readers() {
        Book book1 = getBook1("1");
        Book book2 = getBook1("2");
        Book book3 = getBook1("3");
        Book book4 = getBook1("1");
        Book book5 = getBook1("2");
        Book book6 = getBook1("4");
    }


    public Book getBook1(String id){
        return bookProcessor.getBookk(id);
    }
}


that ApplicationContextProvider class is for get beans of ApplicationContext.
Caching operation is not performed with the above codes.
But when I remove @service and @DependsOn from Readers class and initialize Readers class with new Readers(), the caching operation is done correctly.
Please explain to me exactly what is happening؟
What should I do so that there is no need to new Readers()?

I don't know Spring, but I recall seeing @EnableCaching, e.g. here is a tutorial that might help.

Where do you call new Readers()?

Why not just inject BookProcessor into Readers bean?

@talexmovedtoCodidact in main class :   `  public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    Readers readers = new Readers(); } `


Looks like at some point naked BookProcessor bean get in context and then get replaced by proxy. Solution is simple: replace access with singleton by proper injection.
